Which message is sent when the resource dialog is fully shown?
Which message (if any) is sent when the dialog is fully shown / drawn / the last child control was created/displayed on a resource dialog? Both the dialog and the child controls are created from a resource inside WinMain().
hwndDialog = CreateDialog(hInstance, MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG1), nullptr, DialogProc);
ShowWindow(hwndDialog, SW_SHOWNOACTIVATE);

I want a particular code to run when the dialog is fully shown/drawn.
I tried placing the needed code inside the WM_INITDIALOG and WM_ACTIVATE message handlers but these events seem to be fired before the dialog's content is fully drawn/shown. How do I obtain the message that signifies the on_show_dialog-like state?
The dialog has only standard button controls.

There is no specific message for that particular case. But you can PostMessage your own message to the dialog window after ShowWindow, and then have your DialogProc handle that message.

WM_WINDOWPOSCHANGED with (reinterpret_cast<WINDOWPOS*>(lParam)->flags & SWP_SHOWWINDOW)
